# How to prevent redundant code for interface

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I've got an Interface B that extends Interface A.

Now I want a Class Bravo which implements Interface B.

As I have a Class Alpha which implements Interface A, is it possible just to declare

```
class Bravo extends Alpha implements B
```

and save the implementation of A's Methods due to the facet that Bravo inherits them?

Comment: It only takes about 5 minutes to check this by yourself...

Comment: I've tried that- thank you but my Eclipse marks Bravo as not consistent... further even though SE is Q&A it's good to get some other opinions... maybe it's possible but bad practice... seems not

Comment: I've implemented your classes in a test project and it works fine. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes implementation would be available through inheritance

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me:

```
interface A {
    public void foo();
}

interface B extends A {
    public void bar();
}

class Alpha implements A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

class Bravo extends Alpha implements B {   
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");  
    }   
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bravo bravo = new Bravo();
        bravo.foo();
        bravo.bar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats perfectly possible.
Effectively, `Bravo` will implement `A` and `B` and use `Alpha`'s implementation of `A` as its own.